# SoundCloud API /me/activities/ future_href

Tags: api, soundcloud

What does it meat field `future_href` in SoundCloud API answer from url https://api.soundcloud.com/me/activities.json?

Screenshot: http://f.cl.ly/items/1B110D1y1p0I1I3Y0B0Q/SCDevActivities.PNG

The information, returned from furute_href address contains only one last activity message.

How cat i get early activities?

Comment: If the next page exists, it address will be in `next_href` parameter.

Comment: hint: you should accept nickf's answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `future_href` is a url that will give you newer activities than the ones you just got (that is, ones which haven't happened yet). Use case: you load the activity stream and then every 5 minutes, or via something like 'pull to refresh', poll the `future_href` resource to load new activities.

I believe that it shouldn't contain any items initially, and if it is giving you a duplicate of the previous activity, that's a bug. I'll check with the relevant team.